What is the correct way of leaving a guru?
If a Guru goes astray can a disciple leave him? What do the sastras say about it? I desperately need answer thanks..

Taking another guru is the surest way of abandoning the previous guru. Now it depends on what you mean by the term guru.

Please mention scriptural references thanks

If a Guru has fallen from dharma (due to kanchana / kamini), he is to be abandoned. There's no formal process required for doing this.

Scriptural reference please
